# Android Development : How to ping android emulator from windows?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am using XAMPP , Eclipse on windows.

**Can i ping android emulator from windows? How? With Which IP?**

Note that i can access to localhost(127.0.0.1 on machine) with 10.0.2.2 on android device(emulated).

Answer (score 0):

I think that you must to use telnet for this...

telnet 127.0.0.1 [port emulator device]